# Why do i keep getting the same error message on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Overview:Write a SELECT statement that summarizes the guitar shop’s orders

```
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING MAX(discount_amount)>500
ORDER BY order_id ASC
```

I keep getting this error message: Error code 1055. Expression #3 of select list is not

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: SQL queries usually start with `SELECT`, not `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

use `sum(quantity)` as you are using aggregated function you've to use this also in aggregated way other wise it's need to added in group by clause

```
SELECT order_id, COUNT(*) AS num_items, SUM(item_price - discount_amount) * 
sum(quantity) AS order_total, MAX(discount_amount) AS max_item_discount
FROM order_items
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING MAX(discount_amount)>500
ORDER BY order_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

use quantity in group by as your engine `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

```
   SELECT order_id, COUNT(*) AS num_items, SUM(item_price - discount_amount) * 
    quantity AS order_total, MAX(discount_amount) AS max_item_discount
    FROM order_items
    GROUP BY order_id,quantity
    HAVING MAX(discount_amount)>500
    ORDER BY order_id ASC
```

other wise use `quantity` inside aggregation `sum((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity)`

Answer (score 0):

You have the column quantity not in group by  nut could be you need  move the column inside te sum for item_price - discount_amount

```
    SELECT order_id
        , COUNT(*) AS num_items
        , SUM((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity ) AS order_total
        , MAX(discount_amount) AS max_item_discount
    FROM order_items
    GROUP BY order_id
    HAVING MAX(discount_amount)>500
    ORDER BY order_id ASC
```